# SSRS RDLC: Maximum amount of columns in Report-Grid

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

simple question: Is it possible, that DataGrids in RDLC-Files have an maximum amount of Columns?
I sadly can't tell 100%, if thats the problem, but as soon as we access the loaded LocalReport-Object we get the following exception:

> Fault bucket , type 0 Event Name: CLR20r3 Response: Not available Cab
>   Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: w3wp.exe P2: 8.5.9600.16384 P3: 5215df96 P4:
>   Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common P5: 11.0.3452.0 P6: 53b5e36f P7: c7ba
>   P8: 0 P9: System.StackOverflowException P10:
>
> Attached files:
>
> These files may be available here:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_w3wp.exe_ce795df564245e4fd7919ea7dd5e42b7a9372df_9e3fd63b_29011ad5
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
>   392bcb92-3b4b-11e5-80c4-0050568b0d03 Report Status: 4100 Hashed
>   bucket:

Sadly, I can't dig deeper, what the problem is, so I removed some Columns and it seems to work, when I don't have more than 42 Columns (Oh the irony).

Interesting enought, locally there is no problem, of course only on the System of the Customer.

Comment: Hmm it appears that you have StackOverflow exception

Comment: Yes, my question was if the amount of columns can cause this